# Velocity - multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array, velocity

is there any way to define a 2-dimensional array in Velocity. I was hoping I can do something like

```
#set($matrix[][])
```

and then fill this matrix like this:

```
#set($matrix[1][1] = 'A')
#set($matrix[1][2] = 'B')
...
```

Use Case: I need to generate a 6x6 table with data in each cell. Basically I get the data from a database table and each record contains row index, column index and a value. I was hoping I can do something like this:

```
#forach($record in $databaseTable)
    #set($matrix[$record.rowIndex][$record.columnIndex] = $record.value
#end
```

Any ideas?

BR, Andreas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's definitely possible:

```
## create matrix
#set($matrix = [
  ['A','B',0,'hello',0,0],
  ['C','D',0.56,'there',0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0] ])

## display a cell
$matrix[0][3]

## change some cells
## (warning, indices are zero-based)
#set($matrix[2][3] = 'how are you?')

## display whole matrix in line
$matrix
```

Comment: Thx!!! You saved my weekend!
Just one remark: In order to be able to set a value using #set($matrix[$x][$y]) the entire matrix needs to be initilized with values like in the example above. Initializing by just doing #set($matrix = [[]]) did not work.

Answer (score 0):

##You can use that, i try a 2D array but i can do it, i find this solution

#set ( $test= {  "mytest": [[], []]
} )

#set($dummy = $test.get('mytest').get(0).add('hello'))
#set($dummy = $test.get('mytest').get(1).add('World'))

$test.get('mytest').get(0).get(0) ## hello

$test.get('mytest').get(1).get(0) ## world

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).